# Android Studio's AVD Manager crashes during AVD creation

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

Since the last update of Android Studio (0.8.14) on my Mac OSX, AVD Manager is not able to create AVD anymore.

[image: AVD crash]

It simply crashes during the process. Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a command line to create a new AVD did the trick.

android create avd -n  -t  [- ] ...

http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/managing-avds-cmdline.html

Answer (score 0):

This is the terminal command that worked for me:

```
android create avd -n custom_avd -t 1 --abi default/x86
```

You can find the correct ABI (**default/x86** in my case) using this command:

```
android list targets
```